# JSON.stringify works in console but not in code

Tags: json, stringify

I'm completely baffled.  I have some very simple code that takes an object and converts it to JSON.

```
        var vl = JSON.stringify(this.visibleLayers);
```

This always returns undefined, that is, the variable vl has an undefined value.  Yet when I check

```
JSON.stringify(this.visibleLayers);
```

in the console, it returns the string I expect.  this.visibleLayers is an object, not an array.  What could be going on?

EDIT: Adding more code
Below the is the method this is being called in.  This is using the Dojo AMD style.  Bascially I loop through my map layers and their sublayers to indicate, for each, whether or not the layer is currently visible in the map.  So I end up with an object that looks like

`{"streets":true,"highways":true,...}`

```
submitExportCustomMap: function() {
        domStyle.set("pdfRequestFinished", "display", "none");
        domStyle.set("pdfRequestError", "display", "none");
        domStyle.set("pdfRequest", "display", "block");
        registry.byId("printButton").set("disabled", true);
        this.visiblelayers = {};
        var _this = this;

        array.forEach(map.layerIds, function(layer, i1) {
            var ml = map.getLayer(layer);
            _this.visiblelayers[ml.id] = ml.visible;
            var s = array.forEach(ml.layerInfos, function(sublayer, i2){
                if (array.indexOf(ml.visibleLayers, sublayer.id.toString()) !== -1 && ml.visible) {
                    _this.visiblelayers[sublayer.name] = true;
                }
                else {
                    _this.visiblelayers[sublayer.name] = false;
                }
            });
        });

        this.prepareCommonParameters();
        var vl = JSON.stringify(this.visibleLayers);

        var params = {
            "xMin": this.extent.xmin,
            "yMin": this.extent.ymin,
            "xMax": this.extent.xmax,
            "yMax": this.extent.ymax,
            "Spatial_Reference": this.spatRef,
            "Map_Scale": this.mapScale,
            "Visiblelayers": vl,
            "Layout": this.layout,
            "Map_Title": dom.byId("mapTitle").value,
            "PointGraphics": graph.getFeatureSet("point"),
            "LineGraphics": graph.getFeatureSet("polyline"),
            "PolyGraphics": graph.getFeatureSet("polygon")
        };
        this.cmgp.submitJob(params, lang.hitch(this, this.pdfCompleteCallbackCM), lang.hitch(this, this.pdfStatusCallback), lang.hitch(this, this.pdfErrorCallback));
    },
```

Comment: using `this` in the console returns some value? `this` = `window` in that case?

Comment: No, this = my object as expected, with a visibleLayers property (and others).

Comment: Have you tried calling it as `window.JSON.stringify`? do you have any other `JSON` variable on that scope maybe?

Comment: Same result. The console shows the string properly, the code still shows the variable as undefined.

Comment: Can you show some of the code? maybe there's something in there you're not seeing, if you can't i really don't have any ideas of what's happening sincerly

Comment: added some code as requested

Comment: maybe it's `_this.visibleLayers` and not `this.visibleLayers`?

Comment: I tried _this.visibleLayers and received the same result.  I'm going to have to manually parse the object and stringify it myself I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Boy do I feel stupid!  It turns out I somehow misstyped visibleLayers.  Declaring the variable I called is visiblelayers, with a lower case l.  Making the stringify call I use visibleLayers, with a capital L.  Making them consistent solved all the problems.  D'Oh!